# php preg_replace replace space in text file

Tags: php, preg-replace

i am trying to remove some content from text file using `preg_replace`.Content in text like below

```
1
    *useless*Text
                                    Steve Waugh
```

How to convert content like

```
1    Steve Waugh
```

my code is below.It doesn't work.I don't know where am i making mistake?

```
$content = file_get_contents('test.txt');
$content = preg_replace('/\s[*]useless[*]Text\s/', '  ', $content);
file_put_contents('test.txt', $content);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the indenting before `*useless*Text` so that it is before `Steve Waugh` in the result, you could use a capturing group.

```
\h*\R(\h+)[*]useless[*]Text\s*
```

- `\h*\R` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars and a Unicode newline sequence
- `(\h+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `[*]useless[*]` Match `*useless*`
- `Text\s*` Match `Text` and 0+ whitspace chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x1jE4D/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/CdWa8)

In the replacement use `$1`

```
preg_replace('/\h*\R(\h+)[*]useless[*]Text\s*/', '$1', $content);
```

---

To replace with the predetermined spaces, you could use

```
\s*[*]useless[*]Text\s*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lyv1NV/1)

```
preg_replace('/\s*[*]useless[*]Text\s*/', '  ', $content);
```